# uipagecontrol to show pictures using IB only

Tags: iphone

Is there any functions build into Interface Builder in order to be able to create a page control with multiple pictures allowing the user to scroll between them?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such functions built into Interface Builder.